# Why does If block output vary for stop/warning?

Tags: r

Summary:  Why does the fourth block below (with parentheses around the if block) work correctly to give the error, but the third does not?

I want to have a conditional warning/error based on the date for code that I'm working on.  Specifically, I have an expensive operation to save some excel files that takes several minutes and is rarely required.  If I don't do it, I want to be reminded, and if I don't do it after a date that I expect to have new data, I want an error to remind me.

The first block of code below works reasonably, but I wanted not to duplicate the message.  I tried the second block of code which accurately generates the warning as desired, but when it should be an error (the third block), it returns the function `stop` instead of calling `stop` with the argument as it did for `warning`.

However, when I wrap the if block in parentheses (the fourth block below), it works correctly.  Why does the output of `if` differ between `stop` and `warning`?

```r
today <- Sys.Date()

if (Sys.Date() > today) {
  stop("Not saving excel files")
} else {
  warning("Not saving excel files")
}
#> Warning: Not saving excel files

if (Sys.Date() > today) {
  stop
} else {
  warning
}("Not saving excel files")
#> Warning: Not saving excel files

if (Sys.Date() > as.character(as.Date(today) - 1)) {
  stop
} else {
  warning
}("Not saving excel files")
#> function (..., call. = TRUE, domain = NULL) 
#> {
#>     args <- list(...)
#>     if (length(args) == 1L && inherits(args[[1L]], "condition")) {
#>         cond <- args[[1L]]
#>         if (nargs() > 1L) 
#>             warning("additional arguments ignored in stop()")
#>         message <- conditionMessage(cond)
#>         call <- conditionCall(cond)
#>         .Internal(.signalCondition(cond, message, call))
#>         .Internal(.dfltStop(message, call))
#>     }
#>     else .Internal(stop(call., .makeMessage(..., domain = domain)))
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000000001c2fb4a0>
#> <environment: namespace:base>

(
  if (Sys.Date() > as.character(as.Date(today) - 1)) {
    stop
  } else {
    warning
  }
)("Not saving excel files")
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Not saving excel files
```

Created on 2018-10-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [lobstr](https://github.com/r-lib/lobstr) package on github to compare the abstract syntax trees returned when R parses these commands. Observe the difference.

```
lobstr::ast((if(FALSE) {stop} else {warning})("bad"))
# o-o-`(` 
# | \-o-`if` 
# |   +-FALSE 
# |   +-o-`{` 
# |   | \-stop 
# |   \-o-`{` 
# |     \-warning 
# \-"bad" 

lobstr::ast(if(FALSE) {stop} else {warning}("bad"))
# o-`if` 
# +-FALSE 
# +-o-`{` 
# | \-stop 
# \-o-o-`{` 
#   | \-warning 
#   \-"bad"
```

Notice that in the case without the parenthesis, the `()` to call the function is only bound to the block passed in the else statement. The `()` associates more strongly to the `{}` than it does the result of the `if` statement. Adding in the parenthesis helps you override the default operator precedence.

The `{}` just wrap multiple statements. Consider what it looks like without the braces (which are not required in `if` statements)

```
if(FALSE) stop else warning("bad")
# vs
(if(FALSE) stop else warning)("bad")
```

You can see how it looks like the "bad" should only be passed to `warning` in the first case

Comment: Thanks!  I had misinterpreted the way that braces work with respect to if blocks, and your explanation and `lobstr` ast make it very clear.